# Eclipse in Android adt bundle for windows not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I just downloaded the Eclipse ADT bundle for Windows from

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and the eclipse is not behaving as it normally would.

E.g. ctrl + shift + L pressed twice should open up key binding
alt + left should "go back"

I tried to go into Windows -> preferences and tried changing the "go back" shortcut from ctrl + q to alt + left and then I restarted Eclipse but nothing.

These things kind of bug when you are coding.

How should I go back to the normal Eclipse settings (when you download Eclipse by itself standalone and then add the ADT plugin)

If the above is vague question then just answer me how do I change the shortcuts mentioned in the example above.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are changing the shotcuts seems correct but eclipse has these bugs sometimes, trust me..

You could go to Eclipse's website and download the stand alone version and install the adb manualy folowing the instructions on tis page https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for a little while to see if there are any more answers and then move ahead with this.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left